# No module named kivymd.effects when using pyinstaller

Tags: pyinstaller, kivymd

Hi please anyone could help with this my exe file is throwing up this error when i try to run it and i've added kivymd to my hiddenimports=["kivymd"] in main.spec file also i've tried installing kivymd using pip but still throwing up error.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "kivy\lang\parser.py", line 472, in execute_directives
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivymd.effects'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "kivy\lang\parser.py", line 474, in execute_directives
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivymd.effects'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 28, in <module>
    from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "kivymd\uix\datatables.py", line 307, in <module>
  File "kivy\lang\builder.py", line 373, in load_string
  File "kivy\lang\parser.py", line 402, in __init__
  File "kivy\lang\parser.py", line 508, in parse
  File "kivy\lang\parser.py", line 485, in execute_directives
kivy.lang.parser.ParserException: Parser: File "<inline>", line 3:
...
      1:
      2:#:import DEVICE_TYPE kivymd.material_resources.DEVICE_TYPE
>>    3:#:import StiffScrollEffect kivymd.effects.stiffscroll.StiffScrollEffect
      4:
      5:
...
Unable to import package 'kivymd.effects.stiffscroll.StiffScrollEffect'
```

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with the same issue for some days, so here is the workaround.

pyinstaller is not importing effects module cuz it is not included on kivymd hook list (kivymd_hooks_path), so You need to manually add it:

1st go to ...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\kivymd (or whatever your kivymd path is and modify `__init__.py` to add effects path:

original:

....

```
path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
"""Path to KivyMD package directory."""

fonts_path = os.path.join(path, f"fonts{os.sep}")
"""Path to fonts directory."""

images_path = os.path.join(path, f"images{os.sep}")
"""Path to images directory."""
```

...

modified:

```
....

    path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    """Path to KivyMD package directory."""
    
    fonts_path = os.path.join(path, f"fonts{os.sep}")
    """Path to fonts directory."""
    
    images_path = os.path.join(path, f"images{os.sep}")
    """Path to images directory."""
    
    effects_path = os.path.join(path, f"effects{os.sep}")
    """Path to effects directory."""

...
```

2nd go to ...\kivymd\tools\packaging\pyinstaller and modify `hook-kivymd.py` and add  effects path as well:

```
datas = [
    (
        kivymd.fonts_path,
        str(Path("kivymd").joinpath(Path(kivymd.fonts_path).name)),
    ),
    (
        kivymd.images_path,
        str(Path("kivymd").joinpath(Path(kivymd.images_path).name)),
    ),
    (
        kivymd.effects_path,
        str(Path("kivymd").joinpath(Path(kivymd.effects_path).name)),
    ),
]
```

once done, create a new distributable and thats it :D

Comment: ok thank you @Marco FC i'll try that and update you an whatever it is

Comment: It worked out fine thank you @Marco FC

Comment: I don't know why but this didn't worked for me...

Comment: Marco, could you please help me? I posted my traces at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70742358/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-kivymd-stiffscroll

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me:

```
python3.9
Python 3.9.5 (default, May 19 2021, 11:32:47) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from kivymd.effects.stiffscroll import StiffScrollEffect
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/username/.kivy/logs/kivy_21-10-02_3.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.9.5 (default, May 19 2021, 11:32:47) 
[GCC 9.3.0]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/usr/bin/python3.9"
[INFO   ] [KivyMD      ] 0.104.2, git-bc7d1f5, 2021-06-06 (installed at "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/kivymd/__init__.py")
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 186 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
print(StiffScrollEffect)
<class 'kivymd.effects.stiffscroll.StiffScrollEffect'>
```

Comment: i don't get you @Dmitry please explain

Comment: i also get the same output as you do but i don't seem to know how to fix the error

Comment: Please, try to run the same command. If it works, then problem is not in kivy installation and you have to provide more details on what exactly you are doing. If it doesn’t than problem is in your environment

Comment: the following link may be helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/382301/how-to-install-opengl-version-2-0

Comment: i'm running it on a virtualenv using git cmd not ubuntu or linux